# Basic Javascript variable / function

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm VERY new to learning programming and I'm following some youtube videos. Can somebody tell me why this won't run in chrome, I've written in in Atom.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Library</title>

  </head>
  <body>
   <script>

   var panda = {
     name: "panda", 
     attack: 18, 
     defence: 10, 
     hitPoints: 20,
     sayName: function() {
       document.write("hello my name is Panda")
     }
   };

   sayName();

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: panda.sayName()

Comment: who names a panda "Shaun"?

Comment: 1) youtube tutorials dont provide accurate information 2) you should start learning with the basics, not with methods

Comment: @SterlingArcher ExpertShaun, apparently

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have no `sayName` variable in the current scope. You have only `panda` variable, which is an object which has `sayName` property. So you may call it via

```
panda.sayName();
```

Comment: By answering a question that can easily be closed as a typo, you open yourself up to downvotes. I won't vote, but I just wanted to give you a fair warning.

Comment: Ok!  but we need to get a chance to Mr.Shaun)

Comment: @dhilt His chance is to use Google first, which he clearly did not.

Comment: google would have been useless for this question

Comment: noted @SterlingArcher and thanks dhilt, I appreciate stack might not be correct forum for people at my level so perhaps somebody can point me in the direction of somewhere more appropriate.

Comment: @ExpertShaun you're doing it the right way, building something is the best way to learn in my opinion. Familiarize yourself with the javascript console, and the MDN docs and you'll be in great shape. Once you learn how to debug, you can google any error and often find it quickly with the right keywords.

Comment: @ExpertShaun Also, you are free to delete your post. Come back again with new good questions!

Comment: I think it was that I didn't UNDERSTAND that I had to use the variable to call the function. So basically, @dhilt you answered my question. Thanks

PS if anyone can tell me what they would have googled to find that, that would be a big help!